# Comparing values pointed at by void pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I need to compare the values of two `void` pointers in C.  In the code below, I'm getting the console print out that they are different. It seems that the comparison is between the addresses contained in these two `void` pointers.

How can I make it so that the code compares values (ie: `1 == 1`) of the `void` pointers and prints `"same"`?

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    void *pi = &i;
    void *pj = &j;
    if (pi == pj) {
        printf("same.\n");
    } else {
        printf("different.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you don't have void pointers then you have int pointers  then *pi == *pj.   But while its a void pointer, it is JUST a pointer, very bad practice to then try and compare what is pointed at

Comment: use `memcmp` E.g. `if(memcmp(pi, pj, sizeof(int))==0){`

Comment: To be more specific, I'm trying to implement a linked list where the nodes store generic void *values. And in the delete method, I'd want to pass a void* item that is compared with values in the linked list to be deleted. But when I tried to compare the two void pointers, even though the values that they point at are the same, the comparison returns false. So, I was wondering if there's a way to compare the values of the pointers?

Comment: @jl987: It is not possible to compare values pointed by `void *` pointers without expilcitly telling the compiler how to compare them. The compiler does not know it. Only you know how to do that. In the simplest case you will have to tell the compiler what types these values have by specifying the exact type in the cast. Alternatively, you can provide the `delete` method with the generic comparison function (which you will supply), just like it is done with the standard `bsearch` or `qsort` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to know what type of data the `void` pointers really point at, coerce the pointers to point to that type, and then dereference the coerced pointers (and assume that the types are comparable using `==`):

```
if (*(int *)pi == *(int *)pj)
    printf("same.\n");
else
    printf("different.\n");
```

It's a lot easier just to compare the original variables:

```
if (i == j)
    …
```

or to use correctly typed pointers:

```
int *pi = &i;
int *pj = &j;
if (*pi == *pj)
    …
```

---

> What happens in the case that I do not know the type of data (assuming that an user will always pass the same type of data to be compared with my linked list delete method)?

Then life gets difficult.  Ideally you get the programmer to pass you a comparator function — see [`bsearch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bsearch.html) and
[`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) from the Standard C library for examples.

Failing that, you need to know the size of the target type and you hope that `memcmp()` will do the job sufficiently well.  That's far from guaranteed — it is not clear that comparing two `double` values with `memcmp()` will always produce the correct answer (it might claim different representations of NaN are different, for example), and comparing `struct` types with padding is fraught, and it wouldn't work correctly for your linked list data type if you're passed the nodes (it might be OK if you're passed the data fields from the two nodes).

If you needed to do ordering rather than just equality (a binary search tree, for example), then the situation is worse — in that case, require the programmer to supply the comparator function.

Comment: What happens in the case that I do not know the type of data (assuming that an user will always pass the same type of data to be compared with my linked list delete method.)?

Answer (score 2):

The pointers *are* different.  If you are trying to compare the integers the pointers point to, then you want

```
if ( *(int*)pi == *(int*)pj ) {
    //some code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u have to type cast the void pointer to type int*

as the compiler doesnt know what type of address the pointer is pointing at, it doesnt know how many bytes to read from the pointer address and compare. try this

```
    int i = 2;
    int j = 1;
    void *pi = &i;
    void *pj = &j;
    if ( (*(int*)(pi)) == (*(int*)(pj)) ) 
    {
        printf("same.\n");
    } else 
    {
        printf("different.\n");
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Then is it impossible to compare the two pointers (assuming they are the same type, but you don't know which type, and hence can't cast into their respective types)?

Comment: how can you not know which type the pointer is.. you are coding the program. as Jonathan pointed out, if u have to use only one type of pointer you dont require the void type, just start with that type (int*). but if u want to keep changing the type of the pointer to point to different values then u need to explicitly type cast it everytime while comparing.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, you are tryng to implement a linked list and do not know the data type of the targets of the pointers.  Your design is wrong: with `void*` pointersyou simply cannot (reasonably or reliably) compare the data without knowing the type.  You need to approach it differently.  The best approach is to implement the linked list as a template class.  Your node class will look something like

```
template <typename T> class Node
{
    private:
        T *m_pValue;
        Node *m_prev;
        Node *m_next;
    ...
}
```

But be aware that you need to be very careful of memory management.  You need to decide who is going to own and manage the objects.  In the class above, the user must manage the objects completely.  If you want to relieve the user of this burden, use autopointers, so your nodes become something like

```
template <typename T> class Node
{
    private:
        std::auto_ptr<T> m_pValue;
        Node *m_prev;
        Node *m_next;
    ...
}
```

In both cases, you can compare the values via

```
Node rhs, lhs;
*(lhs.m_pValue) == *(rhs.m_pValue);
```

and this simply presumes that the T type can be compared via ==, which should be true in most cases.

Note that the suggestions of using memory compare and the like are just dangerous - such comparisons completely ignore the structure and symantics of the underlying data type.

OK, given that this must be in C, make your nodes like

```
struct node
{
    void * m_pValue;
    node * m_pPrev;
    node * m_pNext;
}
```

and require that the user of your linked list must provide you with a pointer to a comparitor function

```
int (comparitor*)(void* lhs, void* rhs);
```

which is exactly what Jonathan Leffler suggested below.  Exactly how to structure all this depends on how your are structuring your linked list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions in c++ though! However, I'd need to implement this in c.

Comment: Woops! Missed that little issue... Of course, that's why C++ was created I suppose, because of issues like this.